# My Min. Android Sdk 14 but My app doesnt work on android 6.0 and earlier?

Tags: android, sdk, crash

My app has a minSdkVersion 14. My app's welcome screen is working fine but second activity is crashing on Android 6.0 and earlier.

My build.gradle
[image: My build.gradle]

My Problemed Activity

```
    Intent IntWellcome = getIntent();
    //----Get Card Count From Previous Activity
    final Integer HowMuchCard = IntWellcome.getIntExtra("StartUpCardCount", 0);

    final GridLayout CardGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.CardHolder);

    //----MyCard is my class that defines card properties.
    final MyCard Cards[] = new MyCard[HowMuchCard];


    for (int i = 0; i < HowMuchCard; i++) {
        Cards[i] = new MyCard(this, i, HowMuchCard);
        Cards[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final MyCard k = (MyCard) view;
                k.Turn();
                k.setClickable(false);ClickError=0;
                TextView TVMyScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVScore);
                TVMyScore.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                if (LastCard > -1) {
                    final MyCard k2 = (MyCard) findViewById(LastCard);
                    //k2.Turn();
                    if ((k2.FrontSideID == k.FrontSideID) && (k2.getId() != k.getId())) {
                        //Match
                        k2.Turnable=false;
                        k.Turnable=false;

                        k.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
                        k2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);
                        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) k.getBackground();
                        rocketAnimation.start();
                        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) k2.getBackground();
                        rocketAnimation.start();

                        Handler h = new Handler();
                        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                k.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                k2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                        },600);

                        //k.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //k2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        score++;
                        point = point+(100);
                        LastCard = -1;
                        TVMyScore.setText(Integer.toString(point));

                        if(score==(HowMuchCard/2)){
                            CardGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            TextView TVMyCongratMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCongrats);
                            TVMyCongratMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //oyun bitti
                        }
                    } else {
                        point = point - 10;
                        TVMyScore.setText(Integer.toString(point));
                        LastCard=-1;
                        Handler h = new Handler();
                        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                k.Turn();
                                k2.Turn();
                                k.setClickable(true);
                                k2.setClickable(true);
                            }
                        },500);
                    }
                } else {
                    LastCard = k.getId();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //------Shuffle Cards
    for (int i = 0; i < (HowMuchCard); i++) {
        int rg = (int) (Math.random() * HowMuchCard);
        MyCard k = Cards[rg];
        Cards[rg] = Cards[i];
        Cards[i] = k;
    }

    //-----Put Cards in GridLayout
    for (int j = 0; j < HowMuchCard; j++) {
        CardGrid.addView(Cards[j]);
    }
```

This code block works perfect on Android 7.0 and others. But It never works after welcome activity on Android 6.0 and earlier.

It Says "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped". My which code doesn't fit Android 6.0 and earlier?

This is Stack trace

```
    10-15 14:14:04.232 3749-3749/greyworkssoftware.memoryskills E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: greyworkssoftware.memoryskills, PID: 3749
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{greyworkssoftware.memoryskills/greyworkssoftware.memoryskills.CardsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060066
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060066
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
    at greyworkssoftware.memoryskills.MyCard.<init>(MyCard.java:99)
    at greyworkssoftware.memoryskills.CardsActivity.onCreate(CardsActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.  Most likely you're trying to use functionality that doesn't exist or works differently on older sdks.

Comment: can you post some crash log or some error message?

Comment: Your Activity code is far from complete.

Comment: I can't say much with this much code.

But a similar error might occur , in case of phones with different screen sizes, when you don't put the image in all the dpi folders for example you have an image in drawable-hdpi but NOT in drawable-mdpi .

I am just guessing that your issue might be with the screen resolutions and not with the OS version